# How to create a new controller for each directive in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive that I want to reference in multiple divs. Each div must have access to the same values. Here is a simplified version:

```
.directive('sampleDir', function() {

  var control = function($scope, $element, $attr) {
    $scope.value1 = '';
    $scope.value2 = '';
  }

  return {
    controller: control,
    link: link // defined in code somewhere and needs access to separate value1 and value2
  };

});
```

So basically each div that uses this directive should have its separate values for value1 and value2, or should have a separate controller maybe? How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

First off, you're using `link` and `controller` wrong.

The parameters you provide in `control()` are the parameters for `link()`. You need to use dependency injection in `control()`.

Secondly, if you want a instance of the controller per directive, you need to use the `scope : true` option in your directive's return;

Answer (score 0):

A separate controller instance (and scope) will get created for each instance of the directive, so you do not have to do anything special here to ensure each instance of the directive gets its own scope.

If you want multiple directive instances which are otherwise unrelated to share state or other data then use a service or factory.

Comment: A new instance of the controller will not be created unless you explicitly tell it to.